# CSS/Javascript dynamic styling not getting applied after Ajax data is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, zend-framework

I am working in zend framework. I am attaching code which is troubling me. Please suggest answers. Below is my controller function which I am triggering through ajax:

```
public function fnshowinfoAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();


    $categoryid= $this->_getParam('categoryid');
    //echo $categoryid;die();
    $bestsellerscategory=$this->view->bestsellerscategory=$this->lobjindexmodel->fngetbestsellerscategoryimages($categoryid);
    $tabledata="";
    $tabledata.='<ul id="flexiselDemo"> ';
    foreach($bestsellerscategory as $bestsellerscategory)
    {
    $tabledata.='<li>
                    <div class="ipad text-center">
                        <img src="'.$this->view->baseUrl().$bestsellerscategory['Modifiedname'].$bestsellerscategory['Mainimage'].'" alt="" />
                        <h4>'.$bestsellerscategory['Productname'].'</h4>
                        <h3>'.$bestsellerscategory['ProductMRP'].'</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="cart-1"></i></li>
                            <li><a class="cart" href="#">Add To Cart</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><i class="heart"></i></li>
                            <li><a class="cart" href="#">Add To Wishlist</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>';
            }
            $tabledata.='</ul>';
            echo $tabledata;
}
```

When this data is retrieved in view file, then no classes are appearing dynamically which are supposed to re-evaluate this html elements on loading of layout.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your complete code of creating table into respective phtml view file and can then send that view instead of echoing complete as string from controller, as calling a view via ajax returns only view without adding layout.

From above code everything seems fine with the code. Might be there can be issue in the view file from where you are calling the ajax.